# use of undeclared identifier 'omp_get_thread_num()'

Tags: c++, opencv, parallel-processing, openmp, pragma

I was trying to train an SVM 1 vs all classifier with OpenCV(c++) in parallel manner since each class can be trained without waiting training of the other classes. While using `#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)` commands, I encountered an error indicating **use of undeclared identifier 'omp_get_thread_num()'**. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you compile with -fopenmp?

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, the header `#include <omp.h>` was missing. After adding this, the problem is resolved. Thanks for other suggestions guys.